# High data usage by OS Services (on Nexus 4)

Tags: mobile-data

Since the update to Lollipop last week, `OS Services` on my Nexus 4 has been using a really large amount of my mobile data (when I'm connected to mobile data).

I've tried the following actions but the it still consumes a large amount of data (about 150MB for 10 mins browsing):

- Disabled auto backup
- Cancelled auto synch of all my accounts
- Cancelled auto upload of any photos / videos

Any idea which `OS Service` could be using all this data?

Any help with this would be appreciated, its getting to the stage where I can't use any mobile data as I'm going to go over my usage limit.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1. try to delete App-Data for Google Play Framework
2. Cfeck if in Browser some Preload is activated (and if its disabled for mobile connections if you can)